# Debugging techniques c++ in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'm developing in visual studio 2013, and have a couple of questions regarding debugging:

1. **Is it possible to have a group of breakpoints that I can enable/disable all together?**  Sometimes I may be working on feature 'a' and then need to work on feature 'b'. Being able to group breakpoints, and disable them all at once would be very handy!
2. **Is it possible to have a variable with one value for the debug build, and another for the release build?** Working with opencv, and when I'm in the debug mode, I like to see data on the image that isn't to be shown in the release, so I've set up one bool variable to control this that I have to keep changing when switching builds!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Yes, as of VS 2010 you can label breakpoints into groups.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293674(v=vs.100).aspx
  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export

Briefly, right click on a breakpoint, click Edit Labels..., then either Add a new one (Ex. **parser**), or select a previous one. To toggle groups by label, go to the Breakpoints window (Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints), and change the criteria "In Column" to Labels, and type **parser** into Search. Then you can toggle the results.

2 - Use conditional compilation macros

```
#ifdef DEBUG
int verbose = 1;
#else
int verbose = 0;
#endif
```

Comment: Fantastic - thanks! I'm glad to see #2 is as simple as that, and #1 is equally as logical!

Comment: I've just tried adding the code for #2 to the main cpp file, only for it to be ignored?

Comment: DEBUG is an example, and assumes you have a standard DEBUG build configuration, plus have it currently selected as the active build.

Comment: I'm not sure about `#ifdef DEBUG`, but `#ifdef _DEBUG` works for me

Answer (score 0):

For the second questions, you can use the pre-processor conditional features:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// Building debug variant
#else
// Building something else
#endif
```